# On two fingers down how to disable Action Move

Tags: android, multi-touch

I have code something like below:

```
switch (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            pinching = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (pinching || ld > 30.0f) {
                pinching = true;
                final float dxk = 0.5f * (lastdx1 + lastdx2);
                final float dyk = 0.5f * (lastdy1 + lastdy2);

                if(zoom * d / (d - dd) >= 4.0){
                    pinching = false;
                    scrolling = false;
                } else {
                    smoothZoomTo(Math.max(1.0f, zoom * d / (d - dd)), dxk, dyk, true);
                }
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        default:
            pinching = false;
            break;
    }
```

here i am trying to put my two fingers down after zooming.My requirement is not to move when maxzoom is reached. But right now everytime action move getting called on action pointer down event.

How can i skip action move in this scenario? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Case you want to perform ACTION_MOVE for only single touch,
then use

```
ev.getPointerCount();
```

This gives the number of pointers. If this count is more than 1 don't perform the move action.

Comment: but if i dont handle pointerCount = 2 then pinch zoom wont happens, which is wrong. I only dont want to handle when image is zoomed max and then two fingers are down.